# Event manager error: Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, error, migration, event-receivers

I'm receiving the following error in my ULS logs when I try to create a new website in a migrated content database.

```
Event manager error: Could not load file or assembly 'xNamex, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ac35d2845be7deb1' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Environment: SharePoint 2010 Foundation

How can I troubleshoot this?
Is there a way for me to bypass this error?

Comment: If your source site was using some custom/third party wsps, you have to deploy them again after migration of database.

Comment: @PrashantLakhlani - Unfortunately I don't have access to the third party software. Is there a way for me to remove the reference call to the missing file or assembly?

Comment: Do you have a site collection acecssible, and only due to this error you are not able to access it?

Comment: @PrashantLakhlani - All the existing site collections are accessible. The problem occurs when i try to create a new site using Site Actions > New Site > Create. In other words, I am not able to create new sites due to this error.

Comment: you can try http://featureadmin.codeplex.com/ to review features with problem in your site. May be by doing so you can track which feature is causing problem and you can disable that feature

Comment: @PrashantLakhlani - Alas, the tool FeatureAdmin did not find the feature that is causing the problem. (Great tool btw). Are there any other troubleshooting possibilities I can try?